# React Native Images Too Small, Can't Resize Without Pixelating

Tags: javascript, react-native, png

I have some PNG icons. I have them each in three sizes; original, @2x and @3x. The sizes are definitely correct, ranging from 16x11 to 48x33. When I use them elsewhere in the app, they appear fine.

I have my icons inside an `Image` which is in a `View` wrapper. When I don't add any sizing to them they appear tiny, way smaller than the image itself. When I add a height and width to the `Image` tag they become pixelated.

This is the component:

```
const ListButton = ({ icon, children: text, onPress, ...props }) => (
  <ListItem style={style.listItem} onPress={onPress}>
    {
      icon && <View style={style.iconWrapper}>
        <Image style={style.icon} source={icon} />
      </View>
    }
    <Left>
      <Text style={style.text}>{text}</Text>
    </Left>
    <Right>
      <Icon style={style.arrow} name='arrow-forward' />
    </Right>
  </ListItem>
)
```

And these are the styles:

```
export default {
  listItem: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 0
  },
  iconWrapper: {
    width: 40,
    height: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: variables.listBackgroundColor
  },
  // todo
  icon: {
    height: 17.5,
    width: 17.5
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: variables.noteFontSize,
    color: variables.listTextColor
  },
  arrow: {
    color: variables.listBorderColor
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to implement the logic yourself, use [react-native-responsive-image](https://github.com/expo/react-native-responsive-image).

Pass all icon sizes to `ResponsiveImage` and it can choose the best-resolution icon for the current screen for you.

```
import ResponsiveImage from 'react-native-responsive-image'
```

…

```
<ResponsiveImage
  sources={{
    1: {icon1x},
    2: {icon2x},
    3: {icon3x},
  }}
/>
```